# How to display the list of recent visited group name?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to display the list of recent visited group's name in a drop down :)
or how can i place group's name in order of recently visited? 
i am displaying the group name in a drop-down menu.

Comment: This would require custom development. Have you done any research or have you thought something about it?

Comment: @PrakashK What i have is: group table in db.
can we make fields of who visited when in db and get it on jsp?

Comment: @PrakashK please tell me if i am wrong and give me some approach!

Comment: You should describe clearly what you have tried. This is platform to find solution for specific problem. If you have already tried something, then please be specific about what issue you are facing in your code.